# Spring Boot HTTP security configuration anonymous filter and a custom filter on a different path

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have experienced a strange problem while trying to configure HTTP security by using *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*. Here is the full configuration class I tried so far:

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "module.client.security.enabled")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Value("${management.endpoints.web.base-path}")
  private String managementEndpoint;

  @Autowired
  private List<ModuleProperties> moduleProperties;

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(this.managementEndpoint + "/**");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().disable();
    http.formLogin().disable();
    // FIXME also doesn't work because of the later http.requestMatchers().antMatchers() calls
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").anonymous();

    http.requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/app/**")
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new ClientResolveFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);

  }
```

What I would like to do is actually enabling anonymous authentication for all endpoints — to prevent *NullPointerException*s when operating on *SecurityContextHolder* — Plus, enabling/adding a custom filter to only a subset or different endpoint path which is `/app/**` in this case.

I expected the above code would work but what exactly happens is the *AnonymousAuthenticationFilter* disabled for all and both filters only work for the path `/app/**` only.

If I remove the `http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/app/**")` part, then *AnonymousAuthenticationFilter* works for all paths as normal. I suspect that the second `.antMatchers("/app/**")` call kinda replaces the former one or substitutes it implicitly which doesn't make sense to me, but I could be wrong.

I tried diving into the source but still confused and cannot find a clean solution to make it work as my expectation. Any ideas and help will be appreciated.

Cheers!

EDIT: I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.2 and the Spring Security version is 5.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Dickson's advice, I found a special bean called `FilterRegistrationBean` provided by spring boot.

Thus, I configured it as a bean which applies a specific servlet filter to only configured paths:

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<ClientResolveFilter> clientResolveFilter(){
  final FilterRegistrationBean<ClientResolveFilter> frb = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
  frb.setFilter(new ClientResolveFilter());
  frb.addUrlPatterns("/app/*");
  return frb;
}
```

This solution worked perfectly for my requirement.

**Pay attention to that** the path string is not an ant matcher now — must be written with single `/app/*` instead of double `/app/**` — it's actually the pattern when we manually configured web.xml file like in the old days :)

Answer (score 2):

The `addFilterBefore` (and other addFilter*) method will add the filter to the filter chain which apply to all request. If you want the filter to apply to certain requests only, then you have to check inside the filter (eg. using `HttpServletRequest.getgetRequestURI()` to check the url).

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the `addFilter*` methods' behavior, didn't know that. Yeap, request matching inside the filter would be a workaround but I don't want to dirty the filter itself by matching logic, better to invert that control/logic somewhere outside.